# How to update file version on a button click?

Tags: c#

I want to increment the version of the xml file when the user clicks button. file version must increment from 1000 to 10001. which means it will be writing to the file every time you click a button.

I want this version to increment from 1000 to 10001 every-time you click new button.

```
 <resheader name="version">
 <value>2.0</value>
 </resheader>
 <resheader name="reader">
```

my coding below. i am lost on how i can update the file version. please help. sorry for asking too much.

```
   int versionNumber = 1000;
    public void versionIncrement()
    {
        try
        {
            versionNumber++;
            lbl_Output_Version.Text = versionNumber.ToString();
            lbl_Output_Version.Visible = true;
        }
   }
```

Comment: What do you mean with *file version*?

Comment: It is an XML file, i want the version to increase. see my update

Comment: how are you opening and parsing the XML file? do you want to work with XML related data classes of .NET Framework or do you want to use regex on a text file to identify opening and closing value tag and then simply replace the content of that tag? Your question is very broad, it is trivial to write something on a text file it is more about how you want to read / parse it.

Comment: Any method that can lead to good results its fine

Comment: Read about 'XElement' on how to open XML files and modify them